# How to Split Time and Date in a Column in R

Tags: r, split

```
Date Assigned
<dttm>             
2017-09-02 14:25:00
```

I am wondering how to separate the date from the time, into two separate columns, for easier plotting.

I have tried the following code, but it has returned `NA`;

```
Hours <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(INV$`Date Assigned`, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", tz ="")), 
                format = "H%:%M")

Dates <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(INV$`Date Assigned`,"%Y/%m/%d",tz="")),
                format = "%d/%d/%Y")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Hours <- format(as.POSIXct(INV$`Date Assigned`, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = ""), format = "%H:%M")

Dates <- format(as.Date(INV$`Date Assigned`,"%Y-%m-%d"), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Output:

```
Hours
[1] "14:25"

Dates
[1] "02/09/2017"
```

Of course if you want them as columns in your dataframe, you need to assign them as such:

```
INV$Hours <- format(as.POSIXct(INV$`Date Assigned`, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = ""), format = "%H:%M")

INV$Dates <- format(as.Date(INV$`Date Assigned`,"%Y-%m-%d"), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Output:

```
        Date Assigned Hours      Dates
1 2017-09-02 14:25:00 14:25 02/09/2017
```